# Excel input field that pulls data from range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an input/search field in an excel sheet that when someone enters data in the field, it starts autopopulating from X Range, when they find the data they want they hit enter and it pulls from Y Range.

Closest I've found is `XLOOKUP`, but I can't get it to work on a field when someone types into that field. I want this to work through column A of the entire sheet, so when the user goes to a new line it does the same as the line above.

So, input data into A4, while typing it search C:C and auto fills in as I type. Once I find what I like I hit enter and it pulls the cell next to the C cell I found the data on, resulting cell data, so D:D column.

[image]

I've tried inputing this into a dropdown validate field, but no go, just errors out:

```
=XLOOKUP(INDIRECT("a9"), C:C, D:D)
```

[image]

Comment: When you say *"auto fills in,"* do you mean it automatically "filters out" anything not matching the X number of characters you've provided in column A so far?  I'm not quite clear on this part, and I believe it to be very crucial to understanding the whole problem.

Comment: Do you even have access to [`XLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)? Note - this very much sounds like you might need VBA - though not sure if "autofilling" is even possible.

Comment: By autofill I mean as the user types it tries to search and match to text in C, and fills in the rest of the name as you type.

Comment: You might be looking for [autocomplete in an Excel drop-down](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html)

Comment: check out the reply by 6StringJazzer at 04-13-2016, 03:32 PM in this [post](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1135233-auto-complete-entries-with-drop-down-list.html) where he suggested to use **Combo Box** without `vba` to autocomplete the search criteria stored in a named range.